# Swing JTextArea caret events

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, caret

Are there any events fired when caret is "blinking"?

(not when position changed or property changed etc, but just blink of caret horizontal line)

How JTextField displays hint (which is disappears when user starts type):

[image]

and **the same** functionality used in JTextArea:

[image]

As you can see, while caret is blinkng, the first letter is overwritten.

Comment: *"Are there any events fired when caret is "blinking"?"* Why on Earth would you need to detect that?

Comment: It would be great to repaint the hint while caret is blinking in case of JTextArea

Comment: Post an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and a description of what you *actually* want to achieve (e.g. "How to display such a hint in a JTextArea"). In any case, the only "event" that is received due to the blinking are repaint events, but you should usually not care about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the method of DefaultCaret

```
protected synchronized void damage(Rectangle r)
```

You can override it and add your code there

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but unfortunately it does not work when component gets visible and no any other events fired

Comment: sorry, I finally got understand. it works as I have expected, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> It would be great to repaint the hint while caret is blinking in case of JTextArea

Check out [Text Prompt](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) for a solution that display a "hint" in the text field and doesn't not require you to play with the Caret.